# stackoverflowtr.com

Tags: discussion

I was googling and found a link to an odd domain which was stackoverflowtr.com.

It looked identical to Stack Overflow, but the domain was obviously different so I wonder what it is? I assume that the site is not legitimate. It seems to have been online since 2017-06.

It is possible to report this site to the domain provider which sold the domain and shut it down somehow since it's clearly a copy which simply clones the content from Stack Overflow and acts as a middle-man. I couldn't find any proof of the site actually being malicious though.